# Return only folders containing files using Powershell

Tags: powershell, file, directory, directory-structure

Suppose I have a directory tree as follows:

```
root
├───A
│   ├───1
│   │       a.txt
│   │       b.txt
│   │
│   ├───2
│   │       a.txt
│   │
│   └───3
├───B
│   ├───1
│   │       a.txt
│   │       b.txt
│   │
│   └───3
└───C
    ├───1
    └───2
```

Using Powershell, I would like to return only the directories which contain files as follows:

```
root/A/1
root/A/2
root/B/1
```

What is the best way to do this using Powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipe the output from `Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse` to `Where-Object` and test if any files exist immediately under each:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse |Where-Object { $_ |Get-ChildItem -File |Select -First 1 }
```

Comment: Always like to see your solutions. Yours and mine are similar save for a difference of `Get-ChildItem` vs `Test-Path` - Is there a functional difference or a performance difference?

Comment: This looks like the cleanest solution to me

Answer (score 2):

From whatever root folder you want to test, you can get all directories where a file exists with this:

```
$path = "path you wish to evaluate"
#recurse all directories under $path, 
#returning directories where there is a leaf child item below it
Get-ChildItem $path -Directory -Recurse | 
  Where-Object { Test-Path "$_\*" -PathType Leaf } |
  Select FullName
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this. Please note normally people attempt to code first, and get help with errors in the code...

Try the below

```
$a = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File *.txt  | sort Count -Descending
$a | Select Name, BaseName, Directory, DirectoryName
```

If you want to select more to view from - **System.IO.FileInfo**

```
$a | get-member
```

Comment: Looks like we chose to approach it from different directions - mine from the top down, yours from the bottom up! In your solution, to yield the result in the question, I think all you would need to do is change your select to `Select Directory -Unique`.

Comment: What's the purpose of `| sort Count -Descending`? FileInfo objects don't have a `Count` property...

Comment: @WaitingForGuacamole with regards to Unique - <https://ridicurious.com/2018/04/13/unique-items-in-powershell/#:~:text=%205%20ways%20to%20select%20Unique%20items%20in,based%20on%20the%20integration%20of%20query...%20More%20>

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen none, a typo on my part.

Comment: If `-Unique` is non-performant, you could always try my approach below, which should not generate duplicate entries.

Comment: @WaitingForGuacamole your barking up the wrong tree :o)... I'm not the one with the problem ;o)

Comment: That's not my intent - really just exploring the topic. I found your solution interesting, but had some other thoughts as well. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

One more way... This gets a list of all directories, then checks to see if each one contains files.

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse -Path 'C:\' |
    ForEach-Object { if ((Get-ChildItem -File -Path $_).Length -gt 0) { $_.FullName }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to the already proposed answers:

```
[System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new(
    [string[]](Get-ChildItem . -Recurse -Filter *.txt).Directory
)
```